# Cause CMAKE to generate an error AT BUILD TIME

Tags: cmake

I know how to generate an error at configuration time with `message()` command. But how to use CMake to force my build to fail?

I can think of something using add_custom_command(TARGET MyFailingTarget POST_BUILD COMMAND myFailingCommand) but that seems really hacky.

Comment: Why is that hacky?  CMake doesn't even run at build time.  It's either Make or Visual Studio or Ninja.  To get CMake to even run at build time you have to create a custom command that will call CMake so it can print an error message.

Comment: I want my build to fail on some specific conditions. And I want to do it in my CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: At the build time the work is entirely inside creating executables, libraries and custom commands/targets. When you want to generate an error? For fail custom commands/targets it is sufficient to return non-zero from the `COMMAND`.

Comment: @Korchkidu What specific conditions?  The build tools will already print an error if the build or compile fails.  You want to monitor that the build was a success but print an error message anyways?  You'll still end up with successful build artifacts if you use `POST_BUILD`.  Or you want to monitor for some unrelated event and not allow a build to proceed at all?

Comment: What I want to achieve, is when generating installers from multi-configurations IDE, to make sure that BUILD_TYPE is Release. So maybe there is another way to do it.

Comment: By default everything built in `Release` mode goes into the `Release` folder.  FYI multi-configuration generators don't use `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`.  If you tell the installer tool to grab the files from `Release` and the folder doesn't exist or the files don't exist it should just error out.  Or you check for the existence of the files before the   creating the installer.  But that is just a different question based on what tools you are using.

Comment: @Fred: that would require to start with a clean build which may not be the case. We can imagine scenarios in which I build in Release, then switch to Debug to fix something. Then generate the installers while being in Debug. In that case, I want my build to fail. Anyways, I believe that this is kind of common to generate targets for some build config only or to issue an error for some target on some build config on VS. Or not.

Comment: It is definitely possible to have an error when building a target for the wrong configuration. So in VS if the target should only be built for Release it'll throw an error if attempting to be built in Debug. You may want to update the question with the example CMakeLists.txt that shows how these installers are generated or how they are used.

Answer (score 0):

For the reference, here is what I ended up doing (so similar to what I said in my question):

```
add_custom_command(TARGET onlyInRelease PRE_BUILD
COMAND $<$<NOT:$<CONFIG:Release>>:TARGET_ALLOWED_FOR_RELEASE_BUILDS_ONLY>)
```